# Conditional statement for replacing text inside of an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

There is text generated inside of some span elements in which I would like to replace if the right conditions are met. The text I want swapped out is either "am" (with the intention to switch to a.m.) or "pm" (to p.m.), and the condition is essentially "if this span contains part of a string with 'am' or 'pm', replace that part of the string with 'a.m.' or 'p.m.'.

My html/php looks something like this...

```
<span id="start-time">
  ~Drupal Jargon which essentially outputs something like:~
  5 pm
</span>
```

I was able to swap out the pm in this example with text().replace...

```
$("#start-time").each(function() {
  $am = $(this).text().replace('pm','p.m.');
  $(this).text($am);
});
```

... but the conditional statement I created (seen below) removes the "5 " from the text string inside of the start-time span so it just outputs "p.m.", not the desired "5 p.m.".

```
$("#start-time").each(function() {
  if ($("#start-time").text("pm")) {
    $pm = $(this).text().replace('pm','p.m.');
    $(this).text($pm);
  }
});
```

How can I fix my code so the conditional statement outputs the desired text?

Comment: You have multiple spans with the same ID??

Comment: Yes, but I can switch to classes. They were classes initially but I changed them to id's just to see if I'd get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using "each" (check the docs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you should use callback parameters. 
Not

```
$(".start-time").each(function() {
  if ($("#start-time")..
```

but

```
$(".start-time").each(function(i,e) {
  if ($(e)..
```

Demo here
https://jsfiddle.net/uet5LbLb/

Comment: I feel bad because the last person to answer deleted their comment even though their code 'worked', but I digress- thank you for your more diligent and technically correct answer/demo Diego.